# Evaluation of this definite complex integral

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I want to obtain the symbolic expression for this definite complex integral:

$\int_0^z \frac{1}{b^2+z^2} \, dz$

Then doing a subtition z in the Integral's upper boundary

`z = I*((b*(t - 1))/(t + 1))`

I did the following in MMA..

`ClearAll[j, j1, t, j2]`

`z = I*((b*(t - 1))/(t + 1))`

`j = Integrate[1/(b^2 + z^2), {z, 0, z}];`

`j = j /. z -> (I*b*(-1 + t))/(1 + t)`

Got a error message ?

Some background information

[image: background info]

Answer (score 1):

Make the substitution inside the integral:

```
integrand=1/(b^2 + z^2) /. z -> (I b (t - 1)/(t + 1));
```

calculate dt:

```
dt=D[(I b (t - 1)/(t + 1)), t]
```

do the integral:

```
res=Integrate[integrand dt, t]
```

[image]

To write this as a function of z we need to inverse the replacement:

```
res /. Solve[z == (I b (t - 1)/(t + 1)), t][[1]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks.

What is also important to know is whether MMA can show the outcome of this integral (in a "bookform") as shown in the background picture?

Comment: Must i ask this in  new question then : how to get this "bookform" ?

Comment: The magic word is: "TraditionalForm" Look it up in the help.

Comment: Thanks, yes i know already this TraditionalForm
The question is about the  mathematical form of the answer
i/2b x Log .. to get?

Comment: [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hcvmkuroc55uwei/boekvormbernouilli.png?dl=0)

Comment: How to see the content of this statement ?
`res = Integrate[integrand dt, t]`

Comment: What do you mean? The output of every statement not ended in ";" will be printed.

Comment: @ Daniel Huber Where do you have read this ?
The semi-colon is used for suppressing the output.

Comment: I just said this!

Comment: @ Daniel Huber  It has nothing to do with my person then if I understand correctly what you said