# How to get this expression in a wanted form

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, complex, algebraic-manipulation

This is the endresult of integration calculation
`(I*Log[(b - I*z)/(b + I*z)])/(2*b)`

See the question
[integral calculation post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/263519/evaluation-of-this-definite-complex-integral)

This endresult must transformed to a bookform
[image]

How to do this ?

Answer (score 2):

```
expr = (I*Log[(b - I*z)/(b + I*z)])/(2*b)
```

[image]

For *displaying* `expr` in desired form, you can use [`Defer`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Defer.html) or [`HoldForm`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldForm.html):

```
expr2 = expr /.  pattern : Power[_, -1] Complex[_, _Rational] :> Defer[pattern]
```

[image]

```
expr3 = expr /. pattern : Power[_, -1] Complex[_, _Rational] :> HoldForm[pattern]
```

[image]

To use `expr2` in further calculations, you can replace `Defer` with `Identity`:

```
 100 + 6 b expr2
```

[image]

```
100 + 6 b expr2 /. Defer -> Identity]
```

[image]

For `expr3`, you need to use `ReleaseHold` to remove the `HoldForm` wrapper:

```
100 + 6 b expr3
```

[image]

```
100 + 6 b ReleaseHold @ expr3
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, ,this transformation is not (cannot?) further calculated using manipulation with commands.
It is graphical transformation then.

Comment: With some elementary algebra, I can also easily reduce the integral result to a book form, that's not the problem.
But the question was whether MMA can do that too : and the answer is no then?

Comment: @janhardo, re _"this transformation ..."_, yes; `Defer` and `HoldForm` are used to _display unevaluated forms_ of expressions. Please see the update.

Comment: @kgl3, You made some variations from startform,well done.
My curiosity was to know if MMA would be able to deliver the desired book shape here
The same outcome also showed Maple.
Apparently, you can't bend everything to your will with MMA via calculation into a desired form after all.

Comment: @janhardo I think that the main point that you must accept is that the transformation you desire is a purely graphical one, and is not mathematical in nature. As I understand it, the forms that mathematica chooses to simplify to are often the result of a reduction of `LeafCount`, that is, the number of leaves when representing the expression as a tree graph.

Comment: @CA Trevillian  You can always manually transform an MMA outcome into a desired shape if it is written in the form of a simple fraction.
Problem is how is MMA supposed to know that I want this book form?
How can I know that MMA gives the most simplified expression after a calculation ?

Comment: @janhardo you would tell mathematica your desires, it is not a mind reader, unfortunately. You could likely define something of a `$PrePrint` to automatically rewrite all expressions in such a desired form. To your other question, it is a separate question & depends on your definition of “most simplified”. There are many QAs on this site related to such a thing.

Comment: @CA Trevillian   Yes, I do want to believe that there are even more many forms of a calculated end result does not have the mathematical form that one wants .
In my case it is fraction what can be expressed in more educational form

Comment: @janhardo mathematical forms aside, what you are concerned about here is purely graphical. There is no difference mathematically between the form mathematica outputs and the form you want in this case.

Comment: @CA Trevillian thanks It is no problem at all for me to leave an MMa output like this i had here.
There is no need to edit the output further graphically 
I am so satisfied with the MMA output.

Comment: @CATrevillian Well, I think the real problem is not typesetting, but OP wants to tansform `(b - I*z)/(b + I*z)` to `(b I + z)/(b I -z)`?

Comment: @janhardo Do I understand your question correctly?

Comment: @ xzczd, see question 
Can it be more simplifid the answer with MMA, that i get this book form (see picture)  answer

Comment: @ xzczd, this must clarify more [wanted form](https://www.dropbox.com/s/oxhgpt3xbc9bmfu/uitleg%20wanted%20expression.png?dl=0)